# Posting Data from iPhone to a server exposing OData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, odata

I have a server which is exposing OData services. 
I can actually make use of OData client for Objective C to get the data and show on the iPhone. 
I am wondering what is the process of posting some data into the server from the iPhone.

Assume I have to just send a simple name to the server how would I do that

Any pointers to clogs/sites which provides examples of iPhone apps consuming OData services.

Regards
Hitesh V

Answer (score 1):

To everyone getting to this question to find more info about OData, here's a pointer to some resources and a quick to-do list:

The official Odata Library for iPhone has moved to Github: https://github.com/OData/OData4ObjC/  (although the link posted by Dan remains valid).

Once you clone the repository, you can run the ./odatagen tool (located in the Frameworks/bin folder) to create a pair of .h/.m files to include in your iOS application.

Once you do so, have a look at the included samples (like the Netflix or ODataSampleApp) to have an idea about how it works.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of OData before, but a little googling finds me an Objective-C OData client for the iphone, here: http://odataobjc.codeplex.com/